# URL-dependent processing of GET request and dynamic page creation with JSF 2.0

Tags: model-view-controller, jsf, url-rewriting, get

I just began to dig into JSF 2.0 and it's component-centric architecture with a fixed set of views to build web applications with rich user interfaces. But should JSF 2.0 also be used for web sites with dynamic page creation and many pages? An example:

I have a incomplete database of countries and statistics about those countries for different years. The set of countries and available statistics can change every day. I want to provide URLs like:

- http://domain.com/context/country/germany.html
  (general information about the country)
- http://domain.com/context/country/germany_2012.html
  (statistics about the country for the year 2010)

It wouldn't make sense to create a view for each country, e.g. WEB-INF/pages/country/germany.xhtml or /country/germany.xhtml. I think I really need dynamic page creation based on intensive processing of the given URL. But is JSF 2.0 build for such use-case?

I am really thinking about switching to plain old Servlet in combination of a templating engine like Velocity. My knowledge about JSF 2.0 is very limited and I don't know if I should use it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest, you could create a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/country/*` and forwards all requests to a single JSF view.

```
@WebFilter("/country/*")
public class CountryFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/country.xhtml").forward(req, res);
    }

    // ...
}
```

In the (post)constructor of the managed bean associated with `country.xhtml`, you can grab the original request URI as follows:

```
String originalUri = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
// ...
```

You could use it further in the bean/view to dynamically prepopulate/render the desired HTML output.

For a further abstraction and finer grained configuration, you may want to take a look at [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/), which is doing essentially the same deep under the covers.

Comment: Very interesting approach, but unfortunately FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI) returns null. I am not sure, but maybe this is because phase "Apply Request Values" doesn't get executed?

I was about switching to an action-based framework (Spring MVC), but I think I'll give JSF 2.0 a second chance.

Comment: Well, if it returns `null` then the filter is not invoked at all.

Comment: You're right, just found a typo in my WEB-INF/web.xml. Thanks a lot for your quick and useful solution!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you might want to put the `/country.xhtml` in `/WEB-INF` so that the enduser will be unable to open it directly without calling the filter. I've edited the answer accordingly.